# Linear Regression Model with Many Features - Real Life Example

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I am learning Machine Learning (Linear Regression) from [Prof. Andrew Ng's lecture](https://www.coursera.org/course/ml). While listening when to use normal equation vs gradient descent, he says when our features number is very high (like $10^6$) then to use gradient descent.

Everything is clear to me, but I wonder that can someone give me real life examples where we use such such huge number of features?

[image: a slide from ML coursera lecture]

Comment: Where does the notion that there's a need to compute $(X^TX)^{-1}$ come from? That's not a good idea at all.

Comment: Document classification, bioinformatics (microarray data, genomics, PPI networks, ...), web data mining (Twitter, Facebook, Google, ...), ...

Answer (score 4):

Natural language processing come to mind. For instance, you might predict the amount of money someone spends on your website by their review. The review is text, encoded by an n-gram model. The ith, jth element of your training matrix is the ith customer and counts of jth n-gram. An n-gram is a string of contiguous words like, "the product was excellent."

Typically n-gram data is encoded in a sparse matrix. There are several data-structures suitable. One of the easiest to explain is a coordinate list. A coordinate list is a list of tuples [(i, j, value)]. Since the matrix is mostly zero, this is much more efficient than allocating a dense array.

Answer (score 3):

Another example - image recognition. Imagine that you have just a 512 x 512 gray-scale image - it means that without additional pre-processing you already have $2^{18}$ features - with each pixel being a feature.

It's not necessarily a good example for Linear Regression, but Gradient Descent is used in many ML algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Genetic analysis is another common example. Most mammals have genomes with a number of protein-coding genes in the order of $10^4$, but there's lots of other coding regions (for different kinds of RNA that are not used for protein synthesis directly), too. Additionally, some experimental/methodological procedures bases on sequencing slice the genome into millions ($10^6$) of bins and measure certain molecular features for these bins (like DNA methylation or CpG-islands).